# How to access SQL-DB as AppPool when running ASP.NET Impersonation OR How to get the NT-User when running AnonymousAuthentication

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, asp.net-core

**The tools**
myWebApp: ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC
myAuthApp with IdentityServer4
MS SQL Server 2012
IIS 8 on Win2012 Server
**What we Want:**
figure out what NTUser (intranet) is using the app to get userinfo from sqlserver-db (by searching the NTUserName) without any login dialog
**What we have**
one website (WinAuthApp) using asp.net impersonation (IIS Authentication) only to deliver NTUser-Name with `return User.Identity.Name`
and one website (our WebAPP) with Anonymous Authentication to get access to SQLServer with AppPool Identity. This WebApp redirects (when requesting without authentication token) to our AuthApp to check identity. AuthApp asks the WinAuthApp for the username and searchs the DB for permissionflags and builds an identity and a generates a token for it. with this authentication token it returns to WebApp and is now authenticaticated. External users give Name and Passwort and get a token to access WebApp.
**Problems with this approach**
when external users come to webApp and AuthApp asks WinAuthApp (with WindowsAuthentication configured) they get the NT-Login screen instead of WebApp's "Login Page for Externals". One contraint is: the intranetuser should NOT get a login dialog. (webApp has to answer to links and open the requested page immediately).
**Summary**
How can i configure my AuthApp (IdentityServer4) to have access to current NTUser (IF request comes from Intranet) but mainly working as AppPool-Identity (esp. for DB-Access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

in Web.config set `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"`, and then set WindowsAuthentication true and asp.net impersonation false.

Then access to SQL-Server is done with appPool-Acount, and in the application  `context.User.Identity.Name` gives user's NT-Account.

It wasn't too difficult but i always set WinAuth AND Impersonation synced. Don't know why.

Comment: Is there a solution for standard ASP.NET MVC (not Core) too?

Comment: It must be the same solution in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: No, sorry, in ASP.NET MVC the forwardWindowsAuthToken property is unknown in Web.config and leads to an error ...